# Shimano 105 - Shifter Internal Lever Broken

Tags: shimano, gears, shifter, brake-levers, gearing

[image: Shimano 105 Internal Shift Lever Damage]

I've managed to snap an internal lever (it looks similar to the one on the right side in the pic) in my Shimano 105 (11-speed) right shift - think I just pushed it too far over and it snapped. I can't now shift up gears on rear derailleur.

I'm just trying to decide if I need to get a new lever assembly or I can just get a new part. Unfortunately, I can't even find the name of the part anywhere - so not sure if it's even sold separately than the lever assembly.

Any ideas? I've checked [Shimano](https://dassets.shimano.com/content/dam/global/cg1SHICCycling/final/ev/ev/EV-ST-R7000-4340.pdf) and there's no label for that part - which makes me think it might just be part of the whole assembly.

Answer (score 2):

If the entire lever remains in good condition, and just one part broke, it's commendable that you're trying to fix it rather than to just ditch it and replace.

The last few releases of Shimano 105 are:

- 2014 — [R5800](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/105-5800.html) Series (2x11)
- 2018 — [R7000](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano105-r7000.html) Series (2x11; "toggle")
- 2022 — [Di2](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano105.html) (2x12; electronic)

If the lever you describe is the [ST-R7020-R](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano105-r7000/ST-R7020-R.html)—the pertinent lever in the R7000 groupset, this
[PDF](https://dassets.shimano.com/content/dam/global/cg1SHICCycling/final/ev/ev/EV-ST-R7020-4341C.pdf) shows the Shimano code numbers.

[image: exploded view of the 105 R7020 right shift/brake lever]

The parts for which Shimano provides code numbers are external to the mechanism proper: name plates, cable guides, support ring, ... Since no part numbers are shown for the bulk of the lever's mechanism, this means that Shimano treats it as a single part, one to be replaced when it fails.

Comment: It's generally the case with shimano brifters that you can get the whole thing, the main assembly (for almost as much as the whole thing) and a few little parts. Anything broken in the main assembly means replacing all of it, though some further disassembly is possible

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Shimano treats road shifters as non-serviceable, either by the user or a service center. That being said, I've heard stories of people actually replacing some of the internals using parts salvaged from other broken or used shifters that you can buy online. Still, it's only anectodal evidence and you do it at your own risk if you want to give it a try.

I think it's safe to say that buing a new part is the easiest and most trustworthy way to get on the road again.